# Python: change random element from first column of 2D list

Tags: python, list, random

I have a list:

```
ls = [["a", "b"],
      ["c", "d"],
      ["e", "f"]]
```

I want to change a, c or e to 1. I tried this:

```
import random

for num, row in enumerate(ls):
    r = random.choice(num[0])
    r[0] = 1
print(ls)
```

But I only get:

```
r = random.choice(num[0])
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

How can I change a random element from the first column of 2D array?

Comment: `num` here is the index of the list (in other words a integer). So, you can't use `num[0]`.

Comment: ``num`` is an integer, maybe you want to try with ``row``

Answer (score 4):

Chose random number from 0 to len(ls) - 1 and change the first element in the row:

```py
import random

ls = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"]]

random_row = random.randint(0, len(ls) - 1)
ls[random_row][0] = 1

print(ls)
```

Prints (for example):

```
[['a', 'b'], 
 [1, 'd'], 
 ['e', 'f']]
```